# Kendo Support for Angular 5.x+

Tags: .net, angular5, kendo-angular-ui

I am using **angular 5.2** and I have installed `@progress/kendo-angular-buttons` package. When I'm importing the **ButtonsModule** of this package in my `app.module.ts`, the following exception is coming -

[image]

Here is my code of `app.module`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ButtonsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Please help me to sort this out.